# Adding submenu in QMenuBar

Tags: python, pyqt, qmenu, qmenubar

I have a simple GUI with `QWidget` as my main class and I need to create a submenu like this:

[image: the main class 'QMainWindow']

when i try using `QMenuBar` the result is like this:

[image: main class 'QWidget']

How can i create submenu like the first picture? Should I change my main class to `QMainWindow` if I want the result like the first picture?

***code:***

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Network Automation")
        #self.setFixedSize(350, 500)

        #Menubar
        filemenu = QMenuBar()
        menu = filemenu.addMenu('&File')
        submenu = menu.addMenu('&Open File')

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(filemenu, 0, 1)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('Plastique')
app.processEvents()
window = Widget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please help.

Comment: Yes, you should use `QMainWindow` - it has a built-in menubar.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to change the

`submenu = menu.addMenu('&Open File')`

to

`openaction = menu.addAction('&Open File')`

Comment: and how can i get the same result like first picture, on the second picture i got much margin not like first picture?